# Carousel in Modal with refreshing data

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a page (results.php) that shows results of a search by sending the searched keyword to a file (viewResults.php) using Ajax then the file gets all record with words matching that keyword from the name column in my database and displays the results in a grid view spanning over 70vw (on the results.php). 136px of the 70vw being for a carousel for each result. The carousels work fine they work normally.

There is only 1 blank modal for all the results and this modal is in the results.php, but it changes its contents to show you results depending on which result item you clicked, by having an event that sends through data to a modalResult.php file. When the grid is clicked on, a modal pops up that gives a proper view of the result. Now this modal has information and at the bottom it has a carousel that uses the exact same code as the viewResults.php carousel does, however, the code in my modal doesn't work. When you inspect element and look at the code you see that there are multiple images for the carousel but it stays on one, the code is the same as all the other carousels, and there is no Id for any. Yet my modal's carousel doesn't work even though the code is the same and the inspected element code is the same

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. To make things run more smoothly, please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) of how SO works and especially [How To Ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then please edit your question with more detail so others could help you out.